# Converting Powershell Array to Text so it can be exported to CSV or HTML

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-powershell

I'm trying to convert the output of a powershell (AWS Tools) command to strings so that I can export them to CSV or HTML.  I for the life of me can't figure it out.  I've seen comments on hashtables, naming elements, etc.  Nothing seems to help me.  (I'm very much a newbie).

This is what I got. 
This command

`(Get-IAMAccountAuthorizationDetail).UserDetailList | Select UserName, Grouplist`

Will output this (with better spacing):

UserName      GroupList
--------       ---------
User1          {Admins,Test}
User2          {Admins}

I cant' seem to figure out how to get this data so that it can be converted to CSV or HTML.  Those brackets are an indication its an object, array or something.  Can someone show me the code that would convert this to text or something that the Convertto-CVS o Convertto-HTML commands would work.

The output (subset) of the `Get-Member` Command is this:

TypeName   : Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.UserDetail
Name       : Equals
MemberType : Method
Definition : bool Equals(System.Object obj)

TypeName   : Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.UserDetail
Name       : GetHashCode
MemberType : Method
Definition : int GetHashCode()

TypeName   : Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.UserDetail
Name       : GroupList
MemberType : Property
Definition : System.Collections.Generic.List[string] GroupList {get;set;}

Thanks

Comment: _(Get-IAMAccountAuthorizationDetail).UserDetailList | Select UserName, Grouplist | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation_ is not working? I do not have _Get-IAMAccountAuthorizationDetail_ command but tried it with _Get-ChildItem_ and it works correctly.

Comment: You could do something like the following, which will create a semi-colon delimited list within the `GroupList` cell: `(Get-IAMAccountAuthorizationDetail).UserDetailList | Select UserName,@{n='GroupList';e={$_.Grouplist -join ';'}}`

Comment: No, the output to the GroupList field is ""System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]""

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Admin of things -- That did it! - Almost  I had tried similar things based on generic examples and they never worked, so thank you!    Now... It still holds all the items int grouplist under one set of Quotes and treats it as 1 item.  how can I make each item in grouplist its own :)

Comment: How would you add a second expression to this -- "@{n='GroupList';e={$_.Grouplist -join ';'}}"  Say there was a second field that needed the same thing done to it.

Comment: @stewtenn, the syntax `@{n='Name';e={Expression}}` is called a calculated property. If you want to add another, just add a comma to the end of that line and use that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following, which will create a semi-colon delimited list within the GroupList cell:

```
(Get-IAMAccountAuthorizationDetail).UserDetailList |
    Select-Object UserName,@{n='GroupList';e={$_.Grouplist -join ';'}}
```

**Explanation:**

The syntax `@{n='Name';e={Expression}}` is called a calculated property as explained at [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6). Here is some information about the calculated property:

- It is a hash table with custom properties.
- The first property is `Name`, which is a label for your expression output. `n`,`Name`,`l`, and `label` are all acceptable property names for that property.
- The value passed to `n` is just a string that you are creating. It is the property name that will show up in your output, and it does not need to already exist in your object. Your actual property is called `GroupList`. As an example with `n='All The Groups', the property name would become`All The Groups` in your output. There is nothing wrong with reusing the same name the property currently has.
- The `Expression` or `e` is the ScriptBlock, which is why it is surrounded by `{}`. The ScriptBlock is responsible for producing the value in your custom property.
- `$_` is the current pipeline object passed into the ScriptBlock. This means if you have a collection (just like you do in your case), `$_` will represent each of those items in order.
- If you want to add another calculated property, just add a comma after the last and use the calculated property syntax like so:

  ```
  Select-Object @{n='CustomProperty1';e={$_.ObjectProperty1}},@{n='CustomProperty2';e={$_.ObjectProperty2}}
  ```